# How to measure SPO2 in Tizen native application on GW3

Tags: sensors, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

On GW3 in sensor list I see:
sensor name: SPO2 Monitor Sensor,
sensor uri: http://tizen.org/sensor/healthinfo/spo2_monitor/SENSOR_SPO2_MONITOR

But when I try:

`sensor_create_listener(s_info.sensor.handle, &s_info.sensor.listener); sensor_listener_set_event_cb(s_info.sensor.listener, LISTENER_TIMEOUT, _sensor_event_cb, ad); sensor_listener_set_attribute_int(s_info.sensor.listener, SENSOR_ATTRIBUTE_PAUSE_POLICY, SENSOR_PAUSE_NONE);`

in call back recieve just: **one event with 0 value.**

How make SPO2 measurement in Tizen application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, SPO2 is not a sensor supported by Tizen public API.
This means that it is not open to application developers.

Refer to the link below for a list of sensors that can be used by developers.
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/location-sensors/device-sensors/#sensorlistener

Comment: But what about? https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/location-sensors/device-sensors/#heart-rate-monitor-led-red-sensor
How to get information from the red channel?

Comment: Galaxy watch uses an HRM sensor using green flashing LEDs. I couldn't find the exact spec for galaxy watch, but I found this one(https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_watch-review-1820p3.php). Please refer to the Revised HRM section of this document.